# How does meshlab compute normals by default in Export Mesh?

Tags: meshlab

There's 4 different methods of normal computation under filters. When you click File > Export Mesh As and check Normals, which method does that default to?

Answer (score 0):

It actually save the normals that is using in that moment. They are not recomputed before saving. The default method is an angle weighted average.

http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/vcglib/classvcg_1_1tri_1_1UpdateNormal.html#a16166ceccea0a5152a4ff7fc486047b2

But if your model had per-vertex-normals computed with a different approach, these existing normals are the saved ones.